# Proving Pascal's Theorem for Conics

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

I am trying to prove Pascal's theorem for conics. To do so, I am trying to follow the proof which is given as an exercise in Rey Casse's *Projective Geometry*. Here is the exercise. [image]

In this exercise, they use "." as the product of the two line equations. For example, $(AD).(BC)$ means the product of the equations of the lines $AD$ and $BC$.

I have done parts $(a)$ and $(b)$. However, I am stuck at part $(c)$. How do you finish the exercise?

In $(b)$, the line pairs intersect in L and M. Furthermore, the common points in part (b) are A and D, and also the base points of the last pencil in part $(a)$ are also A and D. Is there a link between these two observations (that might help to finish the exercise)?

Comment: Think about your answer in (b) --- what does $(AB,CD)$ and $(AF,DE)$ intersects mean for $L,M$?

Comment: @user10354138 These line pairs intersect in $L$ and $M$. However, I am not getting how to link this answer to part $(a)$. Of what I see, the common points in part $(b)$ are $A$ and $D$, and also the base points of the last pencil in part $(a)$ are also $A$ and $D$. Is there a link between these two observations?

Comment: The point is to get some value of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ that would contain the intersection $L,M$.  Then $S_1-S_2=0$, and $L,M$ not lying on $AD$ so we get $\mu(BC)-\lambda(EF)=0$ contains both $L,M$, so $(LM)=\mu(BC)-\lambda(EF)=0$ for this $\lambda,\mu$.